# What container I should use

Tags: c#, oop

I have an array of integers, where consecutive groups of three numbers describe:

1. Type: capital (1), current (2), or cash (3).
2. Value of a capital or a current asset, or the exchange rate of a cash asset.
3. Amount.

Input looks like this: 1 500 10 2 25 100 3 10 50 -1 2 5 -1
Where -1 is termination number to exit loop.

What containter should I use?
I was thinking about Dictionary, but it provides only <int,int> type of data. I found out that solution, if there is only groups of two numbers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i += 2)
        {  int key = numbers[i];

            if (key == -1)
                break;
            int priceKey = numbers[i + 1];
            totals.Select(e.Value).Append(-1).ToArray();
```

I know that in C++ there is std::pair which fixes my problem, but I dont know hot wo use Pair in dictionary. Any help with synthax how to use  in my problem?

Comment: No, a dictionary provides `<TKey, TValue>` data, and `TKey` and `TValue` can be whatever type you like, including a type you define that contains properties representing those three fields.

Comment: I think I just need to use Tuple just forgot about this

Comment: Create a proper type to hold the three different values instead. Using `std::pair` is the wrong choice in C++ as well. You have 3 values, not 2

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What's the `2 5 -1` doing after the first `-1`?

Comment: Defining a named tuple or record takes only one line, eg `public record Row(int RecordType, decimal Value, decimal Amount)`. You could make `RecordType` an enum too

Comment: A better solution in C++ would be to have a base abstract class and concrete types for each type of record. The same can be done in C#, using an interface

Comment: @Enigmativity I think the first `-1` should just be `1`.

Answer (score 3):

This is why we have classes/interfaces/types in programming languages.

```
public enum PaymentType {
    Capital, Current, Cash
}

public class Payment {
    public PaymentType Type {get; set;}
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public int Amount {get; set;}
}

// now we can use it and any programmer will easier understand what we are trying to accomplish
var payments = new List<Payment>();
payments.Add(new Payment(PaymentType.Capital, 9, 5))
...

// we can also use dictionaries if we want to 
Dictionary<string, Payment> payments = new Dictionary<string, Payment>()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to define a class for this, C# also has **Tuples**. That would let you have the sample data from the question in an array like this:

```
var data = new (int, int, int)[]{(1, 500, 10), (2, 25, 100), (3, 10, 50), (1, 2, 5)};
```

or in a list:

```
var data = new List<(int, int, int)> {(1, 500, 10), (2, 25, 100), (3, 10, 50), (1, 2, 5)};
```

Comment: This might be better for a school assignment than my answer

Comment: And if one uses [tuple field names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html) even someone who is not the original author of the code will be able to understand what the code is about ...